# Strict Grid system

Tags: theming

I need to setup data in a grid system. The grid itself will be 10*10 and each position in the grid should only contain a single node. I am guessing I will be using VIEWS to great effect to output the grid. But, I still have the following issue:

So, my thoughts are to create a custom content type called 'ITEM'. **Each time an ITEM is created, I need a way to position it within the grid. For instance, if the first ITEM is to be positioned in [ROW:1, COLUMN:1], how can I (i)represent that as part of the node data and (ii)enforce it so that if another user tries to place a second ITEM  in the same position, it will not be allowed.**

Answer (score 2):

My first approach would be to use Nodequeue and create a view for each row. Or, use Nodequeue with a tableless grid using the [Advomatic tutorial](http://www.advomatic.com/blogs/amanda-luker/table-free-gallery-grid-view-drupal-theming).